# Django extending from included template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, include, django-inheritance

I want to divide my base.html template into 2 with some differences in style and html. My structure is like this:

base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <p>same content for both templates</p>
    </head>
    {% if category.title == 'something' %}
        {% include "base-copy.html" %}
    {% else %}
    <body>
        <p>content</p>
        .
        .
        .
    </body>
    {% endif %}
</html>
```

base-copy.html

```
<body>
    <p>content</p>
    .
    .
    .
</body>
```

inside the body content there are several blocks and other templates extend from base.html {% extends "base.html" %}. If i just copy the whole block of code from body into the included template the content is not showing but if I leave it on the original base.html the content is showing... 
Btw I'm using the include statement because otherwise I get the "block" appears more than once error from Django...

any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Can you be more clear in telling which case doesn't work ? Does `{% include "base-copy.html" %}` not work ?

Comment: You can't extend blocks in an included template - see the [note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Comment: yes {% include "base-copy.html" %} does not work.. when I load the page the content from the {% block... %} tags is not showing... the same code if used directly on base.html and not included is showing correctly.. is possible to use same blocks in one template? now i'm getting the appears more than once error..